# how can i change the file name using Input() function in this code ? any correct form of this code

Tags: python, python-3.x

any correct form of this code 
this code form the geeksforgeeks

the code perform correct without

this line "with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/xyz.exe "wb") as file: "

but how to change this xyz.exe using input() funtion

```
import requests 
file_url = "xyz.exe"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream = False) 

file_name = input("Enter your file name")

with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/"str(file_name)"wb") as file: 
    for block in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024): 
        if block: 
            file.write(block)
```

Comment: `with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/" + file_name, "wb") as file:`

Comment: you have tagged this python 2.7 and 3.x, they are vastly different regarding `input()`. But you have a syntax error in your open statement, also you dont need to call str on file name since input returns a string

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7

```
new_file_name = raw_input("Enter file name:")
with open("path/to/{}".format(new_file_name), "wb") as f:
```

Python 3

```
new_file_name = input("Enter file name:")
with open(f"path/to/{new_file_name}", "wb") as f:
```